# How do I make keyframes work on Safari and on Mobile?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have the following div and styles, which work fine for desktop chrome, but doesn't work on safari or on iOS browsers. I'm also using bootstrap 4.

Why doesn't this work in Safari/iOS?

index.html:

```
<h2 id="headline">My dog likes to eat <span class="animate" ></span>.</h2>
```

custom.css:

```
#headline span:after {
  content: 'burgers with cheese';
  -webkit-animation: 8s animate infinite ease-in-out;
  text-color: white;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: 'fish and chips';
  }
  25% {
    content: 'a ceasar salad';
  }
  50% {
    content: 'strawberrys and cream';
  }
  75% {
    content: 'scrambled eggs';
  }
  100% {
    content: 'roast beef';
  }
}
```

Comment: Animating the content property of pseudo elements doesn't support on iOS.

Comment: but it should work on safari desktop, right?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work on both mobile and desktop version of Safari.